# IQueryable model does not contain definition for GetAwaiter and no accessible extension GetAwaiter accept first argument of type IIncludableQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-6.0

I am getting the error above when I try to do a query to the database. This was working fine in .NET 5, but as soon as I created a new project in .NET 6 and using exactly the same query, I'm getting the error - what could I be doing wrong?

This is my code:

```cs
public async Task<IQueryable<Employee>> FindAllEmployees()
{
  try
  {
      IQueryable<Employee> employeeModel = await _employee.Context.employee
          .AsNoTracking()
          .Include(a => a.Policies).ThenInclude(a => a.Product).ThenInclude(a => a.Underwriter)
          .Include(a => a.PrincipalMember); //error appears here

      return employeeModel;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      _logService.LogError(ex.Message);
      throw;
  }
}
```

I tried adding `ToListAsync()` and it sorted the compiler errors out but I then get an error at runtime

> Unable to cast object of type 'Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.IIncludableQueryable`2 to type Generic.ICollection

```cs
IQueryable<Employee> employeeModel = 
    (IQueryable<Employee>)await _employeeContext.Employee.AsNoTracking()
    .Include(a => a.Policies).ThenInclude(a => a.Product).ThenInclude(a => a.Underwriter)
    .Include(a => a.PrincipalMember).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Why you are trying to return `IQueryable`? After materialization, there is no need to work with `IQueryable`.

Comment: Do you want to return the query, or execute it? It looks like you are trying to do both.

Answer (score 1):

You should return `IEnumerable` after materialization. `IQueryable` is not longer needed and may affect performance.

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> FindAllEmployees()
{
    try
    {
        var employeeModel = await _employee.Context.employee
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Include(a => a.Policies).ThenInclude(a => a.Product).ThenInclude(a => a.Underwriter)
            .Include(a => a.PrincipalMember)
            .ToListAsync();

        return employeeModel;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logService.LogError(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

But if you still need `IQueryable` to do not break interface, you can call

```cs
return employeeModel.AsQueryable();
```

But note that this `IQueryable` will be created from `IEnumerable` and will work in-memory with materialized objects.

Comment: Just on one last note the name of the function should be `FindAllEmployeesAsync()` as per convention here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios

Answer (score 0):

For a start, an `async` method should contain something that is awaited. Building a query is executing nothing. You would need to `await` something like `ToListAsync()` and return `Task<IEnumerable<Employee>>`

If this method is part of a repository, the other option is to just `IQueryable`. The method itself does not need to be asynchronous, it can be consumed by both synchronous and asynchronous calls:

```
public IQueryable<Employee> FindAllEmployees()
{
    IQueryable<Employee> query = _employee.Context.employee;
    return query;
}
```

This is a basic wrapper to abstract the DbContext, but a more common use case would be where you have universal low-level rules you expect enforced such as a soft-delete system or multi-tenant authorization check for queries. For example a soft-delete system you might want to default to only look for active records but have the option to see inactive ones:

```
public IQueryable<Employee> FindAllEmployees(bool includeInactive = false)
{
    IQueryable<Employee> query = _employee.Context.employee;
    if(!includeInactive)
        query = query.Where(x => x.IsActive);

    return query;
}
```

Note that we don't have the eager loading statements. The reason for this is that this is a consumption concern. Callers can decide how they want to consume the `IQueryable`, such as to project the data to a view model where `Include` statements are not necessary, or apply additional filtering through `Where` clauses etc. For querying large sets of data like "all employees" I recommend using projection through `Select` rather than dealing with entities and eager loading their entire set of related entities. That is an operation that is better suited to cases where you have narrowed it down to a single or small set of top-level entities.

For example to consume FindAllEmployees `IQueryable` from an `async` controller action that wants to return view models:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<EmployeeSummaryViewModel>> GetEmployeesAsync(SearchCriteria criteria)
{
    var query = _repository.FindAllEmployees();
    // Example search criteria.
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria.FirstName))
       query = query.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith(criteria.FirstName);

    var employees = await query.Select(x => new EmployeeSummaryViewModel
    {
        // populate details from employee and related...
    }).ToListAsync();
    return employees;
}
```

The method can serve synchronous calls as well, by calling `ToList()` etc. against the `IQueryable`.  Since the consumer is executing the query this is also where you would want to place your exception handling.

The advantage of returning `IQueryable` is that your repository can remain a rather "thin" without concerns about how the data might be consumed. The consumers have the flexibility to manage things like eager loading, projection, filtering, pagination, sorting, etc. This is a pattern I promote for facilitating unit testing around business logic in an EF-based project. Note that when mocking the repository exposing `IQueryable` you cannot merely substitute returned sets of data using `new List<T>(...).AsQueryable()` as this does not work for asynchronous operations. There is a Nuget package called MockQueryable which addresses that, with implementations for Moq, NSubstitute, and probably other mocking frameworks. It provides `new List<T>(...).BuildMock()` to return an `IQueryable` that works with `async`.